# How to access application files within a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I'm running a `docker run` command with `check_call()`, but am having trouble figuring out how to access the application files.

I currently have something like

```
check_call(['docker', 'run', <other stuff>, 'python path/to/script/my_script.py'])
```

On my local machine, the file is listed under `/Users/AlanH/Apps/.../MyApp/scripts/my_script.py`

What's the path to execute this script in the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the environment of your Docker container is **isolated** from your host machine, you need to pass a specific `docker run` option `-v /host/path:/container/path` to setup a so-called "bind mount".

Then, your `check_call` command should work accordingly:

```
check_call(['docker', 'run', '-v', '/path/to/your_script.py:/usr/src/your_script.py', <other stuff>, 'python', '/usr/src/your_script.py'])
```

Note that the `host path` and the `container path` need not be identical.

In the example above, the bind mount is a file, but it could just as well be a directory.

For more information, see e.g. the [doc of `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only), or the dedicated page on [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: Why does the path of the container start with `/usr/src`? Is this the standard?

Comment: @AlanH this is just a reflex of mine, to follow the Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) inside the container, but this is not necessary of course. So if you just do `-v /path/to/your_script.py:/app/your_script.py` (with the non-standard `/app` prefix), `-v /path/to/your_script.py:/path/to/your_script.py` (with exactly the same container path as the host path), or any other variation, this will work as well (provided the bind mount does not hide a pre-existing file in the container).